# How I can get fileupload properties from array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I save uploaded files in the array and also show in the grid view. Now I have problem in getting values like file name, file size, file type, file data (binary) from the array. After defining array and add uploaded files to that I try to use below code but it does not show properties of file variable.
For example I like to get binary data of uploaded file (`prjd.Data = file.FileBytes;`
) with below code, but it does not work.

```
public static ArrayList Files = new ArrayList();
foreach (var file in Files)
{


    ProjDocAttach prjd = new ProjDocAttach();
    prjd.ProjDocID = _Projectid;

    prjd.Data = file.FileBytes;

    _DataContext.ProjDocAttaches.InsertOnSubmit(prjd);
    _DataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Another part of code for adding to files array:

```
dt = new DataTable();

DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("File Name", typeof(string));

DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("File Size", typeof(string));

DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Content Type", typeof(string));


dt.Columns.Add(dc1);

dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

dr = dt.NewRow();

dr["File Name"] = FileName;

if (size > 0)
    dr["File Size"] = size.ToString() + " KB";
else
{ dr["File Size"] = fileObj.Length.ToString() + " Bytes"; }

dr["Content Type"] = contenttype;
//  dr["Bytes"] = bytes;
// var x = bytes;
//  var y = dr["Bytes"];
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
GridViewEfile.DataSource = dt;
GridViewEfile.DataBind();
Files.Add(FileUpload1);
```

Comment: Are you adding the whole `FileUpload` Control to the Array???  Files.Add(FileUpload1); In the fisrt code piece you posted, is the only property you need the file bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, I can deduce that you are adding the whole File Upload Control to the Array. DON'T do that!

You can fix you code, by adding to the array only the property you really need to retrieve (at least what you show us you are retrieving), which is the file bytes.

I could make it work, by doing the following:

First of all, I've changed the collection type to a `List<byte[]>`, this collection is strongly typed and is better to use in this case:

```
 public static List<byte[]> files = new List<byte[]>();
```

When the file is posted, add to the list the FileBytes property to the list:

```
// FileUpload1 is the File Upload control declared at the aspx  
files.Add(FileUpload1.FileBytes);
```

To retrieve the file content, do the following:

```
foreach (byte[] bytes in files)
{
    ProjDocAttach prjd = new ProjDocAttach();
    prjd.ProjDocID = _Projectid;
    prjd.Data = bytes;
    // Save to database
}
```

Finally, I have to warn you about using a public static property to handle the uploaded files. When you do that, you are creating a variable at the Application level, so all the users can modify that list, because it's shared. I don't know what you trying to accomplish, but this seems to be very wrong.

Comment: if i want also file name & type what i have to do, i have to use 3 foreach?

Comment: No, in that case I suggest you creating a class to hold your data, having the `byte[] FileBytes`, `string Name`  and `string FileType` properties. Then, change you `List<byte[]>` to `List<MyClass>`, where MyClass is the class you created. So, in every iteration you'll have the all three properties.

Comment: thanks i used list<class> and worked for me after 20 days that i did not know how i have to keep these properties.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is an array of objects, so without casting `file` in your loop to a `System.IO.File` you won't have access to those properties. You don't mention which version of .NET you are using, but assuming it's something remotely recent, then I would recommend using generics, replacing `ArrayList` with `List<System.IO.File>`.